# Is there a standard equivalent to automotive standard AEC-Q200 for the medical sector?

Tags: standard, medical

I want to ensure components of high integrity characteristics are utilised in a design by a third party.

In the automotive sector AEC-Q200 can be stipulated, e.g. (https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/p/panasonic/automotive).  Is there any similar standard that can be stipulated for medical products?

Comment: AEC-Q200 is about stress tested components in cars; but medical device components have potential to harm patients. There is a quality standard applicable to the device manufacturer and their component suppliers, [ISO/CD 13485](https://www.iso.org/iso-13485-medical-devices.html). This standard is now used by the USA [Food and Drug Administration](https://www.fda.gov/medical-devices/postmarket-requirements-devices/quality-system-qs-regulationmedical-device-good-manufacturing-practices). You may perhaps want to specify "clinical grade" components from an ISO 13485:2016 certified supplier.

Comment: I see you're based in Ireland; in USA the FDA requires [Establishment Registration](https://www.fda.gov/medical-device-registration-and-listing) and [U.S. Agent](https://www.fda.gov/medical-devices/medical-device-registration-and-listing/us-agents) to be able to sell a medical device in the USA. Europe may have analagous registration requirements for anyone selling medical devices, even if designed by a third party.

Comment: @MarkU afaik iso 13485 is not necessary for component suppliers.  It refers to the quality around the product.  Try find a full set of components that were on manufactured in compliance with iso13485 for a product design...